`ptxas warning : Registers are spilled to local memory` on Tensorflow and PyTorch
In one of our research, we are using Tensorflow and Pytorch with other major models. Whenever we use our data server at our University, we can use the full GPU in model training. The computer has an Nvidia Titan Xp 12GB GPU.
On the otherhand, my home computer has an Nvidia GeForce RTX 3060 12GB GDDR6 GPU. The problem is, however I try, the models do not use the full GPU during model training. It uses almost 8 and a half GB GPU even though other portions are empty and no other application is using them. Therefore, the epoch takes longer time. Also, I am receiving a warning message in each epoch, even though the dataset, and notebooks are the same.
The codeblock which contains the epoch-related code is given below:
num_epoch = 100
history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    epochs = num_epoch,
    steps_per_epoch = len(train_paths) // batch_size,
    validation_data = test_dataset,
    validation_steps= len(test_paths) // batch_size
)

I am also receiving a warning in each epoch given below even though that might be irrelevant.
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
I0000 00:00:1715325398.195254   36322 service.cc:145] XLA service 0x7f1648003120 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
I0000 00:00:1715325398.195290   36322 service.cc:153]   StreamExecutor device (0): NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060, Compute Capability 8.6
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
I0000 00:00:1715325400.187164   36503 asm_compiler.cc:369] ptxas warning : Registers are spilled to local memory in function 'triton_gemm_dot_4361', 112 bytes spill stores, 112 bytes spill loads

I0000 00:00:1715325456.896302   36322 device_compiler.h:188] Compiled cluster using XLA!  This line is logged at most once for the lifetime of the process.

I was wondering whether there is any way to explicitly force the notebook to use GPU memory at a fixed size. It would be able to reduce epoch time on my home computer. Please let me know what you think about it.

That message is irrelevant. It has absolutely nothing to do with whatever your problem is

It does not use more than 8.5GB from GPU while GPU has a complete 12GB VRAM. Therefore, the performance is also degrading. I need to increase the GPU usage as well to get a decent performance like the server computer have.

Fine, but that has nothing to do with the assembler warning which XLA is emitting when it is compiling something. Please edit your question to make your question clearer. At least half of it is irrelevant as you have posted it

Thank you so much for the clarification on the warning part.

The issue has been resolved.
Version mismatching was creating those issues. I solved the entire issue using a conda environment.
Now the GPU usage is almost 98% as I wanted back then to use the complete available GPU VRAM if that is possible.
The workarounds that fixed the issue:

Create a new Conda environment for Python=3.7.16 using conda create -n fydp python=3.7.16
Here, my conda environment's name is fydp. You can choose different names.
Activate the newly created conda environment using conda activate fydp
Install Tensorflow GPU 2.4.1 using conda install tensorflow-gpu=2.4.1
Install Pytorch 1.7.1 using conda install pytorch==1.7.1 torchvision==0.8.2 torchaudio==0.7.2 cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch
Install separate Jupyter notebook/lab using conda install anaconda::jupyter

That's it! Now the GPU usage is efficient (maximum to the available GPU VRAM memory). Therefore, the epoch time has been reduced as well.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Copy the actual textual output into a code block instead.

I removed the image now.
